# How to add smtp settings to prometheus-operator using helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-alertmanager

I am new to the Kubernetes and especially using helm. I installed the charts and it works fine with default values. I want to the add smtp server setting in the values.yml file for the chart. I am confused on how to inject the values while installing the chart. This is the chart that I am using https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator.
After installing the helm chart with default values I see that there is a deployment called prometheus-operator-grafana which has values GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER and GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD but I am not sure where these values are coming from.
Help with how these values work and how to inject them would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interaction between parent and child chart values is summarize very well in this SO answer: [helm overriding Chart and Values yaml from a base template chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580938/helm-overriding-chart-and-values-yaml-from-a-base-template-chart#49581516)

There are two separate grafana chart mechanisms that control such a thing: [`adminUser` and `adminPassword`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/grafana/values.yaml#L130-L131) or [`admin.existingSecret` along with `admin.userKey` and `admin.passwordkey`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/grafana/values.yaml#L134-L137)

Thus, `helm ... --set grafana.adminUser=ninja --set grafana.adminPassword=hunter2` will do what you want. [The fine manual](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator#grafana) even says they are using grafana as a subchart, and documents that exact setting as the first value underneath the `grafana.enabled` setting. Feel free to file an issue with the helm chart to spend the extra characters and document the `grafana.adminUser` setting, too