# Helm Chart pass variable to dependency

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy Grafana using Helm Chart and dependencies but the values don't get passed down to the Grafana chart.

Chart.yaml

```
apiVersion: v2
appVersion: 7.4.5
name: grafana
dependencies:
- name: grafana
  version: "6.6.4"
  repository: "https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts"
version: 6.6.4
```

Values.yaml

```
grafana:
  persistence.enabled: true
  persistence.size: 5Gi
```

I want to enable persistence by overwriting the **persistence.enabled** variable (which is set to *false* by default) with *true*. I tried doing with `helm install grafana . --set persistence.enabled=true` but nothing happens either, it's always the same deployment.

Edit: I tried this method [helm overriding Chart and Values yaml from a base template chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580938/helm-overriding-chart-and-values-yaml-from-a-base-template-chart) but it didn't work for me. Maybe it's my fault for not understanding how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set value in dependency of Helm chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55748639/set-value-in-dependency-of-helm-chart)

Comment: It didn't work for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please Change below in your values yaml

From

```
grafana:
  persistence.enabled: true
  persistence.size: 5Gi
```

To

```
grafana:
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    size: 5Gi
```

Please always use the default values yaml from helm chart https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/grafana/values.yaml as reference of what your values yaml should contain.

Command Line command will be

```
helm install grafana . --set grafana.persistence.enabled=true --set grafana.persistence.size=5Gi
```