# Different name required to override value in Helm subchart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I have read the [Helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/) and [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55748639/set-value-in-dependency-of-helm-chart) [StackOverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66816213/helm-chart-pass-variable-to-dependency) - this is not (I hope!) a lazy question. I'm having an issue overriding a single particular value in a Helm chart, not having trouble with the concept in general.

I'm trying to install the [Gitea helm chart](https://gitea.com/gitea/helm-chart) on a k8s cluster on Raspberry Pis (that is - on `arm64` architecture). Since the [default memcached dependency chart](https://gitea.com/gitea/helm-chart/src/branch/main/Chart.yaml#L35) is from Bitnami, who [don't support arm64](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/7305), I have overridden the image appropriately (to `arm64v8/memcached`, [link](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/memcached)).

However, this new image has a different entrypoint - `/entrypoint.sh` instead of `/run.sh`. Referencing the [relevant part of the template](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/memcached/templates/deployment.yaml#L75-L91), I believed I needed to override `memcached.args`, but that didn't work as expected:

```
$ cat values.yaml
memcached:
  image:
    repository: "arm64v8/memcached"
    tag: "1.6.17"
  args:
    - "/entrypoint.sh"
  diagnosticMode:
    enabled: false

$ helm template gitea-charts/gitea --values values.yaml
[...]
# Source: gitea/charts/memcached/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: release-name-memcached
  namespace: gitea
  labels: [...]
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels: [...]
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: [...]
    spec:
      [...]
      serviceAccountName: release-name-memcached
      containers:
        - name: memcached
          image: docker.io/arm64v8/memcached:1.6.17
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          args:
            - /run.sh #         <----- this should be `/entrypoint.sh`
          env:
            - name: BITNAMI_DEBUG
              value: "false"
          ports:
            - name: memcache
              containerPort: 11211
[...]
```

However, when I instead overrode `memcached.arguments`, the expected behaviour occurred - the contents of `memcached.arguments` rendered in the template's `args` (or, if `memcached.arguments` was empty, no `args` were rendered)

Where is this mapping from `arguments` to `args` taking place?

Note in particular that the [Bitnami chart docs](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/memcached) refer to `args`, so this is unexpected - though note also that the [Bitnami chart's `values.yaml`](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/memcached/values.yaml#L113-L121) refers to `arguments` in the comment (this is what prompted me to try this "*obviously wrong*" approach!). In the "Upgrade to 5.0.0 notes", we see "[`arguments` has been renamed to `args`.](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/e8c97adb565a848d3a3a84c2e9c2b0b41174d8e6/bitnami/memcached/README.md?plain=1#L328-L337)" - but the Gitea chart [is using a >5.0.0 version of the Bitnami chart](https://gitea.com/gitea/helm-chart/src/branch/main/Chart.yaml#L36).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reasoning is correct. And the current parameter name is definitely called `args` (`arguments` is deprecated, someone just forgot to update the comment [here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/a633b06598e79435e6cc4968b5c77372a183a662/bitnami/memcached/values.yaml#L115)).

Now, why `arguments` work for you and `args`? I think you're just using the old version, before it was renamed. I checked it and:

1. Gitea chart uses [version `5.9.0` from the repo `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitnami/charts/pre-2022/bitnami`](https://gitea.com/gitea/helm-chart/src/commit/6574b1b2320e06d042b80599a8e77575c690f0ac/Chart.yaml#L35)
2. This corresponds to the following Helm Chart: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami/memcached-5.9.0.tgz (you can check it [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitnami/charts/pre-2022/bitnami/index.yaml)).
3. When you extract this file chart, you see it's the old version of chart (with `arguments` not yet renamed to `args`).

Comment: Got it - thanks for helping me work that through! So does that mean that the Bitnami chart's README.md has [incorrect information when it states that `arguments` changes to `args` in version 5.0.0](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/e8c97adb565a848d3a3a84c2e9c2b0b41174d8e6/bitnami/memcached/README.md?plain=1#L328-L337)?

Comment: Given that [this](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/pull/8668/commits) is the PR that introduced that README line, I suspect `5.0.0` was a typo for `6.0.0`.

Comment: yes, I think so.

Comment: Got it - I've opened a PR to correct it [here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/pull/14186). Thanks for confirming!