# Helm Values Replace

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I'm creating a helm package for a application and it's working fine if i use the helm without replacing the values file. But when i try to replace it with the `--values` flag the final yaml is different of what it's supposed to be.

In chart i've included a mariadb data base and added the following PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-mariadb-data
  labels:
    app.funpresp.k8s/part-of: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  storageClassName: {{ .Values.mariadb.storage.class }}
  accessModes: 
    - {{ .Values.mariadb.storage.accessMode }}
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: {{ .Values.mariadb.storage.size }}
```

witch in the package values.yaml is used like:

```
mariadb:
  storage:
    class: resize-sc
    accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
    size: 2Gi
```

That application chart is used in another chart as a dependency. And in the new chart the value is replaced with:

```
mariadb:
  storage:
    class: resize-sc
    accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
    size: 10Gi
```

The expectation here is that the final yaml declares a 10Gi storage size, but it turns out to be 2Gi. To view that yaml i'm running `helm template --debug`

I've uploaded the chart code to https://github.com/bspa10/helmcharts/tree/master/rundeck alongside with the client chart code

Comment: In the parent chart's values, is the `mariadb:` block you show in a block underneath the subchart's name?

Comment: @DavidMaze, the `mariadb` ain't a subchart. They are in my templates folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [helm overriding Chart and Values yaml from a base template chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580938/helm-overriding-chart-and-values-yaml-from-a-base-template-chart)